# IIS vs ASP.Net Threads

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, threadpool, application-pool

Is there a difference between the threadpool that IIS uses to serve static resources and the threadpool ASP.Net uses?

Is it that IIS needs a thread to service a request, and if that request is for a managed resource (e.g. an ASP.Net request that will run managed code), then that request itself has access to a pool of ASP.Net threads?

How can the two values be configured?

How does the concept of a worker process fit into all of this?

Likewise, how does the concept of an application pool fit into this?

Comment: Have a read of: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx